# Pasar una variable de un archivo tpl a otro tpl Smarty

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Tengo un problema, quiero pasar una variable desde un archivo tpl a otro archivo, en el archivo donde tengo la variable que quiero enviar la declaro de esta forma:

> {assign var="codigo" value=$item}

Si imprimo la variable de esta forma **{$codigo}** me muestra el resultado en pantalla sin ningún problema, el problema lo tengo cuando quiero enviar esta variable a otro archivo tpl, en mi archivo tpl donde quiero recibir la variable he colocado un include_file de la siguiente forma:

> {include file='checkout/_partials/address-form.tpl'}

he intentado imprimir mi variable pero no la estoy recibiendo, no se que estoy haciendo mal para poder pasar mi variable de un tpl a otro, mi variable en el archivo donde tengo el tpl la estoy intentando imprimir de esta forma:

> {$codigo}

Comment: Las variables de _Smarty_ solo están disponibles en cada vista, deberías tratar de tomar el valor directamente desde el controlador, justo como haces en la primera plantilla.

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar una variable que está en tu archivo tpl a otro tienes que hacerlo así:

```
{$var} // La variable que queremos pasar
{block name='two tpl'}
    {include file='segundo_tpl.tpl' my_product=$var} 
    // en este tpl tendras el valor de $var usando $my_product
{/block}
```

Comment: Has podido solucionarlo?